# bazel building tensorflow serving error

Tags: bazel, tensorflow-serving

I am running a tensorflow serving container referring to this , all the previous steps are good, but in the last block I met some problems:

```
 git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
 cd serving/
 bazel build -c opt tensorflow_serving/...




 root@15bb1c2766e3:/serving# bazel build -c opt tensorflow_serving/...
```

ERROR:

> /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/clang_toolchain/cc_configure_clang.bzl:3:1:
>   file '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_configure.bzl' does not contain
>   symbol 'cc_autoconf_impl'. ERROR: error loading package '': Extension
>   file 'third_party/clang_toolchain/cc_configure_clang.bzl' has errors.
>   ERROR: error loading package '': Extension file
>   'third_party/clang_toolchain/cc_configure_clang.bzl' has errors. INFO:
>   Elapsed time: 0.107s ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run
>   tests. And in my container, the bazel version is 0.9.0:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this error. First please check whether your Bazel version is 0.5.4 by typing the command `bazel version`.

If the bazel version is 0.5.4 you need to upgrade it to 0.12.0 . For updating you could change Dockerfile.devel BAZEL_VERSION to 0.12.0 and re run all the steps.

Or you could  update bazel directly in the docker container by

1. Download bazel--installer-linux-x86_64.sh from
   https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases location
2. chmod +x ./bazel--installer-linux-x86_64.sh
3. ./bazel--installer-linux-x86_64.sh

I have already answered this on github and it worked. Please refer to the links https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/851 and https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/854

Comment: Works thanks. Downloading the script and running it didn't work for me for some reason but setting the bazel version to 0.12.0 in the docker file worked after a rebuild. Cheers!